# Specify S3 location for model output to sagemaker training job duplication issue

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

Im a using a SageMaker training job to train an ML model, and I am attempting to output the model to a specific location on S3.

Code:

```
model_uri = "s3://***/model/"
script_path = 'entry_point.py'
sklearn = SKLearn(
    entry_point=script_path,
    train_instance_type="ml.m5.large",
    output_path=model_uri,
    role='***',
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)
```

The issue I am having is that the training job will save the model **twice**. Once in the S3 bucket at the top level, and once in the folder specified (`/model`).

Top level:
[image]

Model folder:
[image]

Is this expected behaviour when specifying `output_path` in the estimator? Is there a way to stop it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the top level folder, it will actually contain other information that the job create, whereas the job folder in your Model folder will actually contain the .joblib model (as a tar.gz file) from your process.

Use the `code_location` parameter when creating the `SKLearn` object. For example:

```
model_uri = "s3://***/model/"
training_output_uri = "s3://***/training-output"
script_path = 'entry_point.py'
sklearn = SKLearn(
    entry_point=script_path,
    train_instance_type="ml.m5.large",
    output_path=model_uri,
    code_location=training_output_uri,
    role='***',
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)
```

where the "training-output" folder is created in the S3 bucket.

**Reference:** The `code_location` parameter comes from the [Framework](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.Framework) parent class, which the [SKLearn](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sagemaker.sklearn.html#sagemaker.sklearn.estimator.SKLearn) class is based on.